# Debugging with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a Spring Boot application and everything has been working fine for some weeks; but suddenly I cannot run the application in the debugger (Boot Workbench) although it works fine for running. The problem occurs with all my applications, it is not related to my code. The problem is that originally I was getting a ClassNotFoundException in class java.net.URLClassLoader (line 382). Unfortunately I don't get a stack trace, I cannot see the name in the  View and I cannot write code in the URLClassLoader class. If anyone could instruct me I would post more information. Latelly it breaks in lass SignatureParser without code. I thought that it was a problem caused by an update to Spring Boot and tried running the original version but to no avail.
I have exhausted my search on the Internet but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much clarity on the logs or whether you are seeing it when running the app through an IDE or when building it through something similar to a mvn install.
Clear out your local repository or if its an IDE issue clear the cache. I had similar issues when running certain tests through IntelliJ even though it was working when I was running the tests through the command line.